# How to reactivate customer in softlayer?

Tags: account, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am using the latest version of java api. I found that even in control.softlayer.com ui, failed to re-active the user. I got the error message "{"error":"Subscribing to the notification failed. ERR_NOTIFICATION_USER_SUBSCRIBER_CREATION_DENIED","code":"SoftLayer_Exception_Public"}"

```
    OpenIdConnect.Service service = OpenIdConnect.service(client, Long.parseLong(account.getSlId()));

    OpenIdConnect customer = service.getObjectForOpenIdConnect();

    customer.setSslVpnAllowedFlag(true);
    customer.setUserStatusId(1001l);

    service.editObject(customer);
```

When I disabled the user, I used the same API. Does this caused this problem?

```
    OpenIdConnect.Service service = OpenIdConnect.service(client, Long.parseLong(account.getSlId()));

    OpenIdConnect customer = service.getObjectForOpenIdConnect();

    customer.setSslVpnAllowedFlag(false);
    customer.setUserStatusId(1002l);

    /**
     *  1001 = Active;
        1002 = Disabled; 
        1003 = Inactive; 
        1021 = cancel_pending;
        1022 = VPN Only
     */

    service.editObject(customer);
```

Comment: if you disable the user using the control protal do you get the same issue?

Comment: Yes I see the same issue.. So I decided not to disable the user. Instead, I'm using "Inactive" status.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to submit a ticket with all information that you can provide for further assistance, because I was not able to reproduce this issue. (I had success using the same code that you tried)